# enqueue style sheet and bootstrap

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

i'm struggling with enqueueing the style.css and bootstrap.css files. i tried a lot solutions but no one worked. i also tried like in the video but it didnt work:
https://youtu.be/mtOW2J7zOSk?t=6m28s

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

```
function load_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null);
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', array( 'bootstrap-min' ), null );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles');
```

Directory:

[image: Directory]

Comment: Have you got `wp_head()` in your template's header.

Comment: Hi. Please elaborate _"not working"_. Are there anything being enqueued in your source code? Or only the URLs are incorrect?

Comment: @Picard thank you. i just started to learn how to create own theme. it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

use `wp_head();` before `</head>` in `header.php`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use following syntax:

```
//Load the theme CSS
function theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```